# Cannot install application via OTA

Tags: ios, applications, development

I have created an iOS app that I want to distribute over the air. I have create a website that links to the itms-services url with the mainfest.plist file. When I try to download the file on my iOS device, it prompts me asking if I want to install it, and then it says "App name could not be downloaded at this time". Here is an example:

[image: Example of error]

I have tried re-signing it,editing the manifest plist file, and much more. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have exported the app for "Enterprise Deployment" (or "Ad Hoc Deployment" if this is what you're trying to do).

Then make sure that you have the correct provisioning profile in the package (.mobileprovision).